# How to send request and receive response asynchronously to a .NET webservice by gSOAP2

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, client-server, gsoap

I have a .NET webservice and a client program which was written by C++. The client program is using [gSOAP2](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) to access the web service. The problem is I need to make a client request and receiving the response from server **asynchronously**. I search a lot by google and also read gSOAP user guide in [7.3](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.3) and [7.4](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.4) section but I still don't figure out how to do it. Please help me if you know.

Many thanks,
Tien

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using to develop the C++ client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that gsoap means the same thing by asyncronous as you do, an asyncronous gsoap client fires of a message and then forgets about it; from reading your question my understanding is that you want to start the SOAP request/response process, go away and do something else, and then come back latter or be notified when the response has been returned.

If this is the case then I'd suggest you look at using threads to get the behaviour you want.  Start a new thread to make the call, your main thread can then be notified or can check back when the call has completed. If you need data back from the call then if I was doing this I'd be tempted to write a thread that communicates via a pair of threadsafe queues.  One queue to send requests into the thread and one to pass responses back out. So the main thread writes to the input queue and reads the output queue. If you search on here for C++ threadsafe queue you'll get lots more info.